# Помогите с доступом в классах.

Tags: c#, классы

Ошибка при вводе данных с клавиатуры.

[image: Ошибка]

```
    using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace SimpleClassConlsole
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            ReadProductsArray();
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
        public static int n { get; private set; }

        public static Product[] products = new Product[n];

        public static Product[] Products { set; get; }

        public static void ReadProductsArray()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Введіть кількість товарів:");
            if (!byte.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out byte n))
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Помилка введення значення. Будь-ласка повторіть введення значення ще раз!");

            }


            for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"----------------{i}---------------");
                Console.WriteLine("Введіть ім'я:");
                products[i].Name = Console.ReadLine();
                Console.WriteLine("Введіть ціну:");
                products[i].Price = Convert.ToSingle(Console.ReadLine());
                Console.WriteLine("Введіть кількість:");
                products[i].Quantity = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
                Console.WriteLine("Введіть виробника:");
                products[i].Producer = Console.ReadLine();
                Console.WriteLine("Введіть вагу:");
                products[i].Weight = Convert.ToSingle(Console.ReadLine());



            }

        }

        public static void PrintProducts(Product[] products)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"------------------------------------\n" +
                    $"Товар #{i}: {products[i].Name}\n Ціна: {products[i].Price}\n " +
                    $"Кількість: {products[i].Quantity}\n Виробник: {products[i].Producer}\n " +
                    $"Вага: {products[i].Weight}\n");
            }
        }

        public static void PrintProduct(Product product)
        {

            Console.WriteLine($"------------------------------------\n" +
                $"Товар #: {product.Name}\n Ціна: {product.Price}\n " +
                $"Кількість: {product.Quantity}\n Виробник: {product.Producer}\n " +
                $"Вага: {product.Weight}\n");

        }

        public static void GetProductsInfo(out Product lower, out Product high)
        {
            high = products[0];
            lower = products[0];
            float lowCost = products[0].Price, hightCost = products[0].Price;
            for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
            {
                if (products[i].Price > hightCost) { hightCost = products[i].Price; high = products[i]; }
                if (products[i].Price < lowCost) { lowCost = products[i].Price; lower = products[i]; }
            }
        }

    } 

}
```

Answer (score 3):

Строки:

```
public static int n { get; private set; }
public static Product[] products = new Product[n];
```

Выполняются *до* того, как значение `n` будет установлено в методе `ReadProductsArray`. Поэтому, в момент вызова

```
public static Product[] products = new Product[n];
```

Значение `n` будет равно `0` и создастся массив из 0 элементов.

Из-за этого любое обращение внутри цикла позднее будет вызывать ошибку.

В качестве решения нужно либо создавать массив *после* установки `n`, либо использовать список и не обращаться по индексу, например:

```
public static int n { get; private set; }

public static List<Product> products = new List<Product>();

public static void ReadProductsArray(){
    ...
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        var product = new Product();
        ...
        product.Name = Console.ReadLine();
        ...
        products.Add(product);
    }
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    public static void ReadProductsArray()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Введіть кількість товарів:");
        while (!int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out n))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Помилка введення значення. Будь-ласка повторіть введення значення ще раз!");
        }

        products = new Product[n]; // создать массив после того, как стало известно n

        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        {
          products[i] = new Product(); // создать products[i]
          ...
```